# how to cut a small portion of image using ginput?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image and i want to cut a small region of the image using ginput. I got a rectangle using the following code.how to cut the image in this area?

```
[x1 y1]=ginput(2);
[x2 y2]=ginput(2);
[x3 y3]=ginput(2);
[x4 y4]=ginput(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to separate the maximum rectangular area marked by 4 user inputs, image are can be segmented using the following code segment. Let me know if it does not fulfill your requirement.

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(img);
[x, y] = ginput(4);
img2 = img(min(y):max(y),min(x):max(x));
imshow(img2);
```

Assuming only two user clicks are required at the top left corner and the bottom right corner of the intended region to segment, above code can be slightly modified as follows.

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(img);
[x, y] = ginput(2);
img2 = img(min(y):max(y),min(x):max(x));
imshow(img2);
```

Comment: For your solution, 2 inputs might be enough i.e Diagonal points.

Comment: Thank you @SanthanSalai for your valid point. I have updated the answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: how to zoom the image before cutting?

Comment: You may use imresize before imshow to scale the original image as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to **crop non-rectangular** portion

```
img = imread('hestain.png');

%// Display the image, so that the points could be selected over the image
imshow(img);
[x, y] = ginput(4);

%// getting logical matrix of the polygon formed out of the input points
bw = poly2mask( x, y, size(img,1),size(img,2));

%// replicating the logical array to form a 3D matrix for indexing
bw = repmat(bw,[1,1,size(img,3)]);

out = ones(size(img,1),size(img,2),size(img,3)).*255;
out(bw) = img(bw);

%// if you want the resultant image as same dimensions as of the original image
imshow(uint8(out));

%// if you want the resultant image to be cropped to minimum bounding rectangle
%// inspired from Hwathanie's answer
img2 = out(min(floor(y)):max(ceil(y)),min(floor(x)):max(ceil(x)),:);

figure;
imshow(uint8(img2));
```

Comment: @leenasilvoster Sure, The image i used is 3 Dimensional image. While the `bw` was 2D, i wanted to replicate that(i.e `bw` - first parameter) to 3rd dimension of same size as that of original image. so `size(img,3)`. I didn't wanted to change 1st and 2nd dimensions. so `1,1` did i make u clear?

Comment: @leenasilvoster, it may be a version problem. what error are you getting?

Comment: @leenasilvoster Its a version problem. Check the edit.. i hope it works

Comment: @leenasilvoster, Did you see the white background? Thats becoz, for `uint8` image, `255` refers white and `0` black. while for `double` image, `0` refers black and `1` refers white. [Doc](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76141/discussion-between-user1234-and-santhan-salai).